# User.invite! not sending email in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I am trying to create some tests for my user model. When I invite users to my application using devise_invitable User.invite! creates a user but doesn't seem to log an email. `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count == 0`. In production emails send, and when I use my customer emailer in tests `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` is the right number.

Is there something I am missing in devise_invitable to configure email sending for tests?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on test and development both environments and noticed that it silently returned `ArgumentError - An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.` in log.

I wasn't using `Devise::InvitationsController`, so calling `confirm!` was necessary in my case since `:confirmable` was enabled.

```
User.invite!(invite_params, current_user) do |u|
  u.confirm!
end
```

devise_invitable (1.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a Devise stuff, Rails by default doesn't actually send emails while on test environment, you probably have lines like

```
# Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
# The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

on your config/environments/test.rb, in order to actually send emails you can comment this line and use the ActionMailer configs of your production.rb for example, but this is not recommended since you can use ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array itself to test your emails.